# Why does $(I-T)S_k-I$ equal $I-T^{k+1}-I$?

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, operator-theory, banach-spaces, normed-spaces

Consider a Banach space, $X$, and $T\in\mathcal B(X)$ where $\|T\|\lt1$. Take as well that $S=\sum_{n=0}^\infty T^n$ so that it's $k$th partial sum is given by $S_k=\sum_{n=0}^k T^n$. Suppose as well that $\{S_k\}$ converges to $S$ in $B(X)$.

**Why is it** that,

$$(I-T)S_k-I=I-T^{k+1}-I$$

and not that,

$$(I-T)S_k-I=S_k-T^{k+1}-I\,?$$

(This is part of the proof of the Neumann series theorem, which says that under the above conditions, $I-T$ is an invertible operator and it's inverse is given by $\sum_{n=0}^\infty T^n$).

Comment: Use the fact that $TS_k = S_k + T^{k+1} - I$.

Comment: Just multiply. The sum telescopes. $(I-T)S_k=S_k-TS_k=(I+T+...+T^k)-(T+T^2+...+T^{k+1})=I-T^{k+1}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to write in lowercase. 
\begin{align}
(1-t)s_k  - 1 
&= s_k - ts_k - 1 \\
&= 1 + t + \ldots + t^k- t(1 + t + \ldots + t^k) - 1 \\
&= 1 + t + \ldots + t^k- (t + t^2 + \ldots + t^{k+1}) - 1 \\
&= 1 + t + \ldots + t^k- t - t^2 + \ldots - t^{k+1} - 1 & \text{cancel common terms}\\
&= 1  - t^{k+1} - 1.
\end{align}